# How to count the number of same items on two different lists in SAS

Tags: sas

I am looking for the best way to count the number of executives shared by two firms.  Currently, the data is arranged such that each row contains two firm IDs and a list of identifiers for each the board members of each firm.

Currently, I have managed to obtain what I need by looping through each item in the first list using a scan function and then using an index function to compare the item to the second list.  When scaled up to several dozen executives and hundreds of millions pairs, this is woefully slow and inefficient.

A simple working example is below.  The example returns no matches for the first pair, 1 match for the second pair, and 2 matches for the third pair.

```
    data test1;
    INPUT year idfirm1 idfirm2 list1 $17-61 list2 $63-108;
    datalines;
    2000 1001 1002 106146||110716||156790||170648||175076||185060 108178||138024||162445||166960||221521||228814
    2000 1001 1003 106146||110716||156790||170648||175076||185060 108178||138024||162445||166960||221521||106146
    2000 1001 1004 106146||110716||156790||170648||175076||185060 108178||138024||162445||166960||110716||106146
    ;
    run;

    %macro loop2;
    %do m = 1 %to 6;
    test&m=scan(list1,&m,'||');
    if test&m ^= ' ' and index(list2,strip(test&m)) > 0 then match&m = 1;
    drop test&m;
    %end;
    %mend;

    data test2; set test1;
    %loop2;
    N_overlap = sum(of match:);
    if N_overlap = . then N_overlap = 0;
    run;
```

The data can be rearranged easily (i.e. leave IDs as numbers, wide, long, etc.) to best count the number of overlapping executives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is probably a bit to broad for SO, since you probably have infinite ways to solve the actual problem. But, I'll give my way to address the general assignment.

One way to solve this is by rearranging your managers to a more overcoming dataset, where you have every `manager` per `firm` and `year`. By having this, you can use a `left outer join` to get any overlap per manager. When you have your overlaps, it is easy to calculate which companies that has the most overlaps.

```
data work.managers;
INPUT year idfirm manager;
datalines;
2000 1001 106146
2000 1001 185060
2000 1002 108178
2000 1002 228814
2000 1003 108178
2000 1003 106146
2000 1004 108178
2000 1004 110716
2000 1004 106146
;
run;

proc sql;
create view work.manager_overlap as
select t1.manager, t1.year, t1.idfirm as idfirm1, t2.idfirm as idfirm2
from work.managers t1
left join work.managers t2
  on t1.year = t2.year and t1.manager = t2.manager
where t1.idfirm < t2.idfirm
order by t1.manager, t1.year, t1.idfirm, t2.idfirm;

proc sql;
create table work.manager_overlap_count as
select t1.idfirm1, t1.idfirm2, t1.year, count(t1.manager) as n_overlaps
from work.manager_overlap t1
group by t1.idfirm1, t1.idfirm2, t1.year
order by n_overlaps desc, t1.idfirm1, t1.idfirm2, t1.year;
```